# Windows updates for non-existant updates

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-10, windows-update

For a while I have been stuck with updates for Microsoft Office 2013 products that would always fail. I tried researching the error, but answers on the official microsoft forums were completely nonsensical boiler plate answers. With the release of Office 2016 preview I had both installed at that point. Eventually, deeming that 2016 was stable enough, I decided to uninstall 2013 to try and rid myself of these windows update failures.

**Unfortunately, the updates are still trying to install themselves, and are continuing to stop me from installing security updates that I actually want.**

Anyone have any ideas or experience with this issue?

*Note:
This issue seems very specific as I have not been able to find any resources on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well unfortunately, the only way to rid myself of these update shenanigans was a clean install, which probably is completely undesired for most people. :\

Answer (score 0):

If you have some other office components installed that were primarily for other MS office version, they will still be getting updated.

Like, Even when I have office 2016 installed, I also have word viewer installed and also excel viewer installed. These are probably office 2003 or office 2007 components, as Microsoft might be categorizing them, so when my 2016 updates are coming, I also get office 2007 updates which are for word/ excel viewer.

There is also a "compatibility software" which needs to be installed separately from office, that enables older (pre office 2003?) file extensions like .doc .xls to be accessed from later office, so this component, categorized probably as office 2003 component, will still be updated in 2016.

Which non-2016 components of ms office are still in your box?

Thanks.